# Wrongly applied git stash to a different branch

Tags: git, git-stash, git-revert

I was initially working on a branch, say A and stashed some of the changes in that branch using `git stash save <message>`. Upon completion of my work in that branch, I switched to a different branch B, and then wrongly typed `git stash apply` thinking I was on branch A, which resulted in conflicts in couple of files on branch B.

I tried doing `git checkout` and `git reset HEAD` on those files, but it says the files are unmerged and I am unable to bring my branch back to the original state.

Is there any way I could bring my branch B to original state or revert the stash I applied to branch B wrongly?

UPDATE : As per the latest answer, running git reset HEAD and then git checkout --  does fix the issue. But it might be time consuming if there are several files in the list as in my case, is there a better way to reverse all these changes in just one attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the unmerged files if you don't want the changes you have to do:

```
git reset HEAD <filename>
git checkout -- <filename>
```

Git always tells you what to do to get the files to a different state (add to staging, discard changes) when you do `git status`. Most of the time following the instructions on screen will help.

To get the whole branch to the state of the last commit `HEAD` (dot [.] means all in the current working directory):

```
git reset HEAD .
git checkout -- .
```

Comment: Doing git checkout -- <filename> makes git to report "path <filename> is unmerged". Running git status shows all the file list as "both modified". Can we revert back the stash altogether in a single attempt without having to run through each file?

Comment: thanks...it worked :) I may have been mistakenly following the wrong order